# Convert Redis subscribe []uint8 output to string

Tags: go, redis, publish-subscribe, redigo

I am using the code mentioned below to get output from Redis Publish-Subscribe. The message passed during the Redis publish a string (`test-message`).

However, the output that I get during subscribe stage is of type `[]uint8`. Following is the output that I get when I run the below mentioned code `[116 101 115 116 45 109 101 115 115 97 103 101]` (instead of `test-message` which is the intended output.

This is caused by this line in the below mentioned code `fmt.Println("Output: ", v.Data, reflect.TypeOf(v.Data)).`

**How can I get correct output that I desire in Subscribe in the aforesaid line (i.e. `test-message`)?** I feel that I may need to convert from `[]uint8` to `string` to get the correct output.

My code is given below. I used this [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68839793/how-to-receive-redis-publish-message-in-go/68840236#68840236) as a reference for my code.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "reflect"
    "time"

    "github.com/gomodule/redigo/redis"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Start redis test.")

    c, err := redis.Dial("tcp", "localhost:6379")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    } else {
        log.Println("No error during redis.Dial.")
    }
    // defer c.Close()

    val := "test-message"

    /// Publisher.
    go func() {
        c, err := redis.Dial("tcp", "localhost:6379")
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        count := 0
        for {
            c.Do("PUBLISH", "example", val)
            // c.Do("PUBLISH", "example",
            //  fmt.Sprintf("test message %d", count))
            count++
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        }
    }()
    /// End here

    /// Subscriber.
    psc := redis.PubSubConn{Conn: c}
    psc.Subscribe("example")

    for {
        switch v := psc.Receive().(type) {
        case redis.Message:
            //fmt.Printf("%s: message: %s\n", v.Channel, v.Data)
            fmt.Println("Output: ", v.Data, reflect.TypeOf(v.Data))
        case redis.Subscription:
            fmt.Printf("%s: %s %d\n", v.Channel, v.Kind, v.Count)
        case error:
            fmt.Println(v)
        }

        time.Sleep(1)
    }
    /// End here

}
```

Comment: @mkopriva : Your suggestion works. Thanks. Do you want to put your comment down as an answer? I will accept it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[]uint8` is synonymous with [`[]byte`](https://pkg.go.dev/builtin#byte) and a byte slice can be converted to `string` using a [conversion expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions_to_and_from_a_string_type).

> 2. Converting a slice of bytes to a string type yields a string whose successive bytes are the elements of the slice.
>
> ```
> string([]byte{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', '\xc3', '\xb8'})   // "hellø"
> string([]byte{})                                     // ""
> string([]byte(nil))                                  // ""
>
> type MyBytes []byte string(MyBytes{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', '\xc3',
> '\xb8'})  // "hellø"
> ```

So the following should be enough:

```golang
string(v.Data)
```

You can also print the string without conversion by using the `%s` verb in `fmt`:

```golang
fmt.Printf("Output: %s", v.Data)
```

---

Example: https://play.golang.org/p/JICYPfOt-fQ

```golang
data := []uint8(`test-message`)
fmt.Println(data)
fmt.Println(string(data))
fmt.Printf("%s\n", data)
```